# How to compute (x MOD y) with just SUM and MULT gates?

Tags: circuits, turing-completeness

It is known that $\{ SUM, MULT \}$ is Turing-complete, i.e. every Turing machine has an equivalent circuit made up of $SUM$ and $MULT$ gates.

By the way, I could not come up with designing $MOD$ function with $SUM$- and $MULT$-only circuit. How can one construct such a circuit?

P.S. The Turing machine is simple. Assuming $\#x\#y\#$ as the input, it suffices to go back and forth and cross $y$ of the remaining entries of $x$ as much as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turing machines and circuits are very different models of computation: Turing machines are a *uniform model* and circuits are a *non-uniform model*. Turing machines accept inputs of an arbitrary length, whereas circuits accept inputs of a fixed length. We can convert Turing machines to equivalent circuits in which the properties of the machine we started with are reflected. For example, a Turing machine running in polynomial time can be converted to a sequence of circuits of polynomial size.

If we have a sequence of circuits, one for each possible length of input, we can interpret the sequence as computing a function. As mentioned above, one way of generating such a sequence of circuits is from a Turing machine. Circuits which can be generated *by* a Turing machine, which accepts $n$ as input and outputs the circuit handling inputs of length $n$, are known as *uniform circuits*. (There are various more refined notions of uniformity, in which the Turing machine has some resource restrictions.) However, not all sequences of circuits arise in this way. For example, if $L$ is any length in which membership depends only on the length of the input, then $L$ can be computed by a sequence of circuits. However, $L$ need not even be computable. For example, consider the language of all inputs of length $n$ such that the $n$th Turing machine halts on the empty input.

You say that $\{SUM,MULT\}$ is Turing-complete, but there are a few problems with this statement. First, you seem to think of SUM and MULT as *gates*, which are components of circuits. As explained above, a model for circuits can't really be Turing-complete, though a set of gates can be complete in the sense that using it you can compute any function. Second, we usually (but not always) think of circuits as Boolean-valued. You haven't explained what the domain of SUM and MULT is, but I suspect that it is not $\{0,1\}$. In that case you have to explain exactly what circuit model you are interested in, and what notion of completeness you are interested in: while Boolean circuits can compute all functions $\{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$, the same doesn't necessarily hold in other circuit models such as algebraic circuits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, where can I read more on the topic of Turing-completeness of the circuit models, both algebraic and Boolean?

Comment: Turing-completeness doesn't really apply to circuits.